# Как сохранить содержимое FlowDocument в виде текста?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, flowdocument, richtextbox

Данные из FlowDocument сохраняются внутри файла txt в байткоде:

< text_rich>e1xydGYxXGFuc2lcYW5zaWNwZzEyNTJcdWMxXGh0bWF1dHNwXGRlZmYye1xmb250dGJse1xmMFxmY2hhcnNldDAgVGltZXMgTmV3IFJvbWFuO317XGYyXGZjaGFyc2V0MCBDb25zb2xhczt9fXtcY29sb3J0YmxccmVkMFxncmVlbjBcYmx1ZTA7XHJlZDI1NVxncmVlbjI1NVxibHVlMjU1O1xyZWQyMjFcZ3JlZW4yMjFcYmx1ZTIyMTt9XGxvY2hcaGljaFxkYmNoXHBhcmRccGxhaW5cbHRycGFyXGl0YXAwe1xsYW5nMTAzM1xmczIwXGYyXGNmMiBcY2YyXHFse1xmMiB7XGx0cmNoIHNoZHNoZ2QxMTF9XGxpMFxyaTBcc2EwXHNiMFxmaTBccWxccGFyfQ0KfQ0KfQ==

Сохранять нужно в виде обычного текста "ТЕКСТ123". Остальное содержимое документа (картинки...) можно оставить в байткоде.
.

```
    public static byte[] FlowDocumennToBlob(FlowDocument document)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        TextRange tr = new TextRange(document.ContentStart, document.ContentEnd);
        tr.Save(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
        byte[] blob = stream.ToArray();
        stream.Close();
        return blob;
    }

    public void RichTextBox_(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        var blob = FlowDocumennToBlob(text_rich.Document);
        node.text_rich = new byte[blob.Length];
        node.text_rich = blob;
    }
```

Comment: А зачем вы создаёте `node.text_rich` и тут же затираете его?

Comment: Ну вы сохраняете в формат Rtf, мало ли что и как там кодируется? Хотите человекочитаемый формат (зачем??), сохраняйте в текст.

Comment: без создания нового массива  `node.text_rich = new byte[blob.Length];` происходит ошибка

Comment: Какая ошибка? Вы, надеюсь, понимаете, что вы создаёте массив и тут же затираете ссылку на него?